# Advanced CSS data selectors - SASS or RegEx?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, sass

I dream of declaring this hypothetical CSS rule:

```
div.parent[data-foo="X"] > div.child[data-bar="X"]{ ... }
```

Where X is not explicitly defined. I know this is not normally possible. My first thought was RegEx, but a Google Search and on SA revealed that's just never happening. *However,* I've seen some crazy SASS logic that I never thought possible in CSS, so I thought I'd ask.

The alternative to what I'm wishing for is:

```
div.parent[data-foo="1"] > div.child[data-bar="1"],
div.parent[data-foo="2"] > div.child[data-bar="2"],
div.parent[data-foo="3"] > div.child[data-bar="3"],
div.parent[data-foo="4"] > div.child[data-bar="4"]{
  ...
}
```

Thanks for your time and advice.

Comment: Is there a number range for [data-foo="X"]? i.e. 0-100?

Comment: Sass compiles to CSS, so if it's not possible in CSS, then neither is it possible using Sass. I suspect whatever solution you write in Sass will eventually become the CSS "alternative" that you have already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest solution i've found that, although not dynamic, uses a SASS macro to save from writing it all out.

```
$catalog: xxx1 yyy2 zzz3;

%selector {
    display: block;
} 

@each $prod in $catalog {
    #parent[data-top="#{$prod}"] > .child[data-bot="#{$prod}"]{
        @extend %selector;    
    }    
}
```

Compiles to ....

```
#parent[data-top="xxx1"] > .child[data-bot="xxx1"], 
#parent[data-top="yyy2"] > .child[data-bot="yyy2"], 
#parent[data-top="zzz3"] > .child[data-bot="zzz3"] {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a attribute selector like this aswell.

```
div.parent[data-foo] > div.child[data-bar] {
    /* Your styles */
}
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is looking for, they want to ensure that the parent and the child have the same value for the specified attribute.